# after retired or after retiring or after retirement?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, infinitive-vs-gerund, future-time

I am preparing a speech about the life after retire. But not sure which one is correct below.

> 1. After **retire**, I want to be a happy person.
> 2. After **retirement**, I want to be a happy person.
> 3. After **retired**, I want to be a happy person.
> 4. After **retiring**, I want to be a happy person.

I searched in internet, it seems "After retired" is a correct expression because retired can be an adj.

Comment: Yes, *retired* can be used like an adjective, but you can't say "after *adjective*".  It doesn't make any sense.  Think about it with other adjectives: *after red*?  *after tall*?  What would they mean?

Answer (score 1):

A few correct options (changes italic):

1. After *I* retire, I want to be a happy person. [The verb *retire* requires a subject. Unlike some languages, English usually allows an implied pronoun subject only in commands.]
2. *In* retirement, I want to be a happy person. [This one sounds a little unidiomatic to me, but it's correct. *Retirement* is the state of being retired; "after retirement" would be when you are no longer retired (e.g., you have started working again).]
3. *When [or "Once"] I am* retired, I want to be a happy person. [See below for explanation. This wording *could* be interpreted as you being forced into retirement.]
4. After retiring, I want to be a happy person. [Correct as it stands, but some people might interpret it using another meaning of *retire*, which is "to go to bed."]

> I searched in internet, it seems "After retired" is a correct expression because retired can be an adj.

*Retired* is an adjective, as you noted, but the construction you are using requires an adverb modifying the main verb. In the meaning you were using, *after* is a preposition and requires a noun or equivalent (a noun clause, in my edited version) as an object. I would use *when* or *once* in this case because they are less likely to be interpreted as forced retirement than "After I am retired" is. (Strictly, "After I am retired" either means someone is retiring you or means that you are no longer retired.)